# Switch Case in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do a `case` statement. The code looks like this:

```
def true?(verbosity)
  verb = verbosity.to_s
  case verb
  when verb.match?('yes')
    true
  when verb.match?('y')
    return true
  when verb.match('ja')
    true
  when verb.match?('j')
    true
  when verb.to_i(10).eql?(1)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Regardless of what I write in the `case` statement, even when the debugger says `options[:verbosity]` is `"yes"`, the `case` statement instantly jumps to `false` and leaves the function. I even added explicit casting to it as string.
How do I have to write the statement to get a valid evaluation?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code you show here is too long. Please give a minimal example what illustrates your issue.

Comment: The problem is that all of those things like `verb.match?('yes')` evaluate to `true`, but it's not looking for `true`, it's looking for something that matches `verb`. so this is equivalent to saying `if verb == true return true else if verb == true return true else return false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this form, when you want to evaluate all `case` conditions separately, you should omit `verb` in the beginning, like this:

```
case
when verb.match?('yes')
  true
when verb.match?('ja')
  true
# ...
```

that said, don't you think it would be easier to read and nicer if you used regular expression magic to make this whole method much shorter? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
def true?(verbosity)
  verb = verbosity.to_s
  verb.match?(/yes|y|ja|j/i) || verb.to_i.eql?(1)
end
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still just jumps out of the case and returns false

Comment: @Patrick.H are you sure the correct value is passed as an argument into this method?

Comment: yes I am but your second function is just awesome! you are right it is easy to read and this function works wonderful. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can write `case verb; when 'yes', 'ja';` etc.

Comment: ..or `%w| yes y ja j |.include?(verb.downcase)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a direct fix:

```
def true?(verbosity)
  verb = verbosity.to_s
  # If you wish to reference `verb` below in the branches like this,
  # then DON'T make it the subject of the `case` statement:
  case
  when verb.match?('yes')
    true
  when verb.match?('y')
    return true
  when verb.match('ja')
    true
  when verb.match?('j')
    true
  when verb.to_i(10).eql?(1)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Or, here's a cleaner use of a `case` statement (without changing any behaviour above):

```
def true?(verbosity)
  case verbosity.to_s
  when /yes/, /y/, /ja/, '1'
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

...But this is doesn't quite do what you want, since it will return `true` for e.g. "yellow", but `false` for e.g. "TRUE". So, how about:

```
def true?(verbosity)
  case verbosity.to_s
  when /\A(yes|y|ja|1)\z/i
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

..But at this point, you may be thinking - why bother with a `case` statement here at all?? The other answer has already shown how you can take this a step further by removing the `case` statement; or alternatively you could even do this in 1 line and without a regex:

```
def true?(verbosity)
  %w[yes y ja j 1].include?(verbosity.to_s.downcase)
end
```

Also, I note that there is some ambiguity in your post about whether this parameter is supposed to be called `options[:verbose]` or `options[:verbosity]`. It's unclear whether or not this has manifested as a bug in your complete code, but I felt it's worth mentioning.